# Online white board application?

Tags: web

I'm looking for a online scratching site, that allows me to type while others can view my text but not able to modify it, is there some sites like that ? And best do not require login

Comment: Please check the FAQ, questions about web applications are off topic on superuser.

Comment: It might be on topic on webapps.SE, but have it migrated there instead of asking it again.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch Recommendation questions are off topic for Web Apps too, so they're rarely migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google docs for the purpose.